# Javascript how subclass extend parentclass event handler?

Tags: javascript, oop

some thing like these:

```
function myinput(input){
     input.on('click',this.check)
     this.check = function(){....}
}

function mynewinput(){
     input.on('click',this.newcheck)
}

mynewinput.prototype = new myinput();

mynewinput.prototype.newcheck = function(){....}
```

what i want is subclass method "newcheck" extand or cover "check", but these code only run old "check",how to do this? thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this could work

```
function myinput(input) {
  input.on('check', this.check);
}
myinput.prototype.check = function() {...}


function mynewinput(input) {
  myinput.call(this, input);
}
mynewinput.prototype = new myinput();
mynewinput.prototype.check = function() {myinput.prototype.check(); ...}
```

Comment: is this overwrite check()?how about extend old check? can i do that?

Comment: myinput.prototype.check()  can be myinput.check()?

Comment: myinput.prototype.check() and myinput.check() is not the same. myinput.prototype and myinput are two different objects.